# How do I target a VirtualBox VM when setting up IntelliType application-specific settings on a Mac

Tags: mac, virtualbox, intellitype

I would like to have specific options set up for Virtual Box VMs, but when I set these up for the VirtualBox.app they only apply to the manager application and not the VMs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the VMs run using a different application, one contained within VirtualBox.app. The Add Application dialog does not allow you to browse deeper into the .app file (like you'd normally do by using "Show Package Contents" in Finder).

One workaround to this is to create a symbolic link to the application that's running VMs. Here's an example command (that you'd run in the Console) that would achieve this:

```
ln -s /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app ~/Applications/VirtualBoxVM.app
```

This creates a symbolic link in your personal Applications folder. Now in IntelliType you'd browse to your own Applications folder and select the VirtualBoxVM application.